# "isset" is not piking up button click

Tags: php

I'm trying to create delete button, in front of each row in a table. Each button id = value (book_id) taken from a data table. However, when I click the button it does not run the code inside isset function.

```
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<th>BOOK ID</th><th>BOOK NAME</th><th>PRICE</th>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))            
        {                
            echo "<tr>";
                $book_id = $row['book_id'];
                //echo $book_id.'<br>';
                echo "<td>" .$row['book_id']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['book_name']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['price']. "</td>";
                //echo "<td><a href='edit_user.php?id=""'</a>Edit</td>";
                // echo "<td><a href='db_actions/delete_user.php?id=" .$row['book_id']. "'</a>Delete</td>";
                echo '<td><center><input type="submit" id='.$book_id.' name="Delete" value ="Drop"><center></td><tr>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

[image]

But when I use the following code it does not output anything. What could be the issue?

```
      if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) 
      {
         $ID = $_GET['id'];
         echo $ID;
      }
```

Comment: Form isn't set to `POST`? Where's the `form` code? Does it load a new page? The images do not help with the question.

Comment: Adding data through form is working. I want to output book id when drop button is clicked

Comment: The value is sent, not the id.

Comment: Element id won't be sent via POST or GET as is client side only.

Comment: If it were to be it would not be `$_GET` either, it would be `POST` as the form submits everything via the same method.

Comment: `I want to output book id when drop button is clicked`...your button isn't part of a `<form>` so it won't submit anything.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, `<center>` is deprecated in HTML. Use CSS styles instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: `$ID = $_GET['id'];` doesn't make sense if you're submitting via POST. Use `$_POST` to read values submitted by a POST request - unless the `action` of your (currently nonexistent) form still contains URL parameters of course, then it would work. But I wouldn't advise that for a delete operation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Ill try through form. I did not wrapped the button inside a form earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap a complete form around that button for it to work as a form, also I suggest putting the `book_id` into a hidden field to get it back to the page script

I also remove the deprecated `<centre>` tag, use css instead

```
echo '<td>
            <form action="db_actions/delete_user.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$book_id.'">
                <input type="submit" name="Delete" value ="Drop">
            </form>
    </td>';
```

Comment: Your hidden input lacks a `name`... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Ill try through form. I did not wrapped the button inside a form earlier

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, knew I had missed something